# Apache 2.4 restrict access

Tags: apache-2.4

I got the following directories in my /var/www/htdocs:

```
test123/
test123/cache/
test456/
test456/cache/
test789/
test789/cache/
another_directory/cache/
```

I would like to achieve this:

- access to / for everyone
- access to /test123/test.htm + /test456/test.htm + /test789/test.htm for the ip-address 192.168.1.10
- no access to all cache-directorys

So I got the following apache 2.4 configuration, but it is not working as expected, because I am still able to access the cache-directories test123/cache, test456/cache and test789/cache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs

        <Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory  ~ "/var/www/htdocs/test(123|456|789)">
                Require ip 192.168.1.10
        </Directory>

        <Directory  "/var/www/htdocs/*/cache">
                Require all denied
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Quotes [from the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging):

> - `<Directory>` [...] is processed in the order shortest directory component to longest. For example, `<Directory "/var/web/dir">` will be processed before `<Directory "/var/web/dir/subdir">`.
> - If multiple `<Directory>` sections apply to the same directory they are processed in the configuration file order.

This makes your case a little difficult.

From the second statement I'd interpret that it should only be necessary to switch the order of the two `<Directory>` directives:

```
<Directory  "/var/www/htdocs/*/cache">
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory  ~ "/var/www/htdocs/test(123|456|789)">
        Require ip 192.168.1.10
</Directory>
```

If the first matches, it gets denied. Otherwise the second directive should match.

The first statement, however states that the shortest directory is processed first. The shortest here would be the `<Directory  ~ "/var/www/htdocs/test(123|456|789)">`. In that case the order doesn't matter and you will have to look for another solution.

I can't test it right now, so just try to switch the two statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was not aware of the shortest first, I think I missed that information in the documentation. I already tried to change the order in the configuration file and it did not help :(